# Adding an index variable for interaction diary data

Tags: sas, do-loops

I am working on an interaction diary data set. I got this data file sent to me cleaned, but the people that cleaned it did not add an index variable that I need for analyses. So:

Participants completed survey questionnaires for every interaction that they had over X number of days. This means that participants may have multiple records (interaction diaries) for each day. To do the analyses, I need 3 index variables - Person_id, DiaryDay, and InterOnDay. Like this:

| Person_ID | DiaryDay | InterOnDay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2300 | 1 | 1 |
| 2300 | 1 | 2 |
| 2300 | 2 | 1 |
| 2300 | 2 | 2 |
| 2300 | 2 | 3 |
| 2300 | 3 | 1 |

I have the first two index variables, but am missing InterOnDay.

Of note, the number of diarydays vary by person, and the number of interactions recorded vary by person and diaryday.

I think I need to do DO loops, but I have just utterly failed at figuring out how. Does anyone have suggestions for how this code might look?
This is what I have so far, but I know this is not enough code.

```
DATA WORK.TEST;
SET WORK.DT;
by ID DATETODAY; 
do IntOnDay = 1 to ;
  output;
end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
data have;
input Person_ID DiaryDay;
datalines;
2300 1
2300 1
2300 2
2300 2
2300 2
2300 3
;

data want;
   set have;
   by Person_ID DiaryDay;
   if first.DiaryDay then InterOnDay = 0;
   InterOnDay + 1;
run;
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Virtual hug to you. You saved my sanity. I see it was not hard code. But when you look in the wrong place and keep banging your head... Thank you so much.

Comment: I know the feeling. Have a nice day :-)